# labels in macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am running a macro that I had used to create multiple line graphs that are created as an output in the next sheet.  I need to add in ***custom data labels*** for the line graphs. I can't seem to get the vba for the custom labels to select `(Cells(i, 10), Cells(i, 21))` as custom labels.

Comment: Did you try to use the Macro Recorder? It might help to figure out how the correct code looks like.

Comment: unrelated, but i wanted to point out that if your data is not contiguous you may not get the last column on your `LastColumn` line because `xlToRight` will stop once there is a blank cell gap

Comment: When you say custom labels do you mean that each of those is a point label or is it an axis label or chart name or?

Comment: Also, can you create a mock version of your data to upload a picture?

Comment: #Marcucciboy2, can you please help

Comment: you're kind of all over the place with consistency in this question. Your initial question was for the labels to be from column 10 to 21 but your updated version is from 1 to 12 among other small differences and additions that were not mentioned in the initial question.

Comment: Please create a simple mockup of your data in excel and upload a screenshot of it so that I can get concrete locations for your data

Comment: It really doesn't matter where the labels are. Could be 1 to 12 or 10  to 21,as long as they are 12 consecutive.

Comment: I cannot upload images. Is there another way to show it to you?

Comment: By a simple mockup I mean change the data axes/titles and the numbers themselves so that the information is no longer private and is safe to be shared as a picture

Comment: I mean stack overflow does not permit me to upload a picture. it added a link instead right on top of the question.

Answer (score 1):

To set the name of the 5th line to say "Downtown" your code would be something like:

```
chrt.SeriesCollection(5).Name = "Downtown"
```

To make sure that your data points have labels, you can check and/or set

```
chrt.SeriesCollection(5).HasDataLabels = True
```

To change the label of the 3rd point to "North"

```
chrt.SeriesCollection(5).DataLabels(3).Text = "North"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: OP references "`(Cells(i, 10), Cells(i, 21))` as custom labels", not naming the line (?)

Comment: This names my series. I need to change the data labels, not the series name.

Comment: @confusedexcel Sorry I misunderstood. Consider editing your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I just did. Does this help ?

Comment: Yes !! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
Sub AddCharts()

    'variable declaration
    Dim sheetSource As String
    sheetSource = "sheet5"      'update with sheet name

    Dim sheetDestination As String
    sheetDestination = "sheet6" 'update with sheet name

    With Sheets(sheetSource)
        'Find the last used row
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    End With

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim rangeSource As Range
    Dim rangeLabels As Range
    Dim cel As Range

    'Destination sheet is selected bcoz charts will be inserted here
    Sheets(sheetDestination).Select

    'Looping from second row till last row with data
    For i = 2 To lastRow

        With Sheets(sheetSource)
            'set the chart source
            Set rangeSource = .Range(.Cells(i, "D"), .Cells(i, "O"))  'your sheet confused me on the end column

            'pick the range of labels
            Set rangeLabels = .Range(.Cells(i, "AM"), .Cells(i, "AX"))
        End With

        'Adds chart to destination sheet
        Set chrt = Sheets(sheetDestination).Shapes.AddChart.Chart

        With chrt

            'set the chart as a line chart
            .ChartType = xlLine

            'set chart source
            .SetSourceData Source:=rangeSource

            With .SeriesCollection(1)
                .name = Sheets(sheetSource).Range("Q1").Value2
                .XValues = "{""July"",""Aug"",""Sep"",""Oct"",""Nov"",""Dec"",""Jan"",""Feb"",""Mar"",""Apr"",""May"",""June""}"
                .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
            End With

            'add another series of data
            .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Sheets(sheetSource).Range(Sheets(sheetSource).Cells(i, "P"), Sheets(sheetSource).Cells(i, "AA"))

            .SeriesCollection(2).name = Sheets(sheetSource).Range("P1").Value2

            'turns labels on
            .SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels

            j = 1
            For Each cel In rangeLabels
                .SeriesCollection(2).DataLabels(j).Text = cel.Value2
                j = j + 1
            Next cel

            .HasTitle = True

            'move the chart to left and below previous charts
            With .ChartArea
                .Left = 1
                .Top = (i - 2) * .HEIGHT
            End With

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

The bit that most relevant to your changes is this:

```
j = 1
For Each cel In rangeLabels
    .SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(j).Text = cel.Value2
    j = j + 1
Next cel
```

because it loops through the range with label text in it, `(.Cells(i, "AM"), .Cells(i, "AX"))` and applies those cell values as labels to the data points in order. I have not done much error handling so if there are more labels than data points it will probably break on you.

Comment: It does not work. I have edited the codes to show the codes i have so far.

Comment: @confusedexcel updated. if it does not work this time, please describe exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Error msg:
    Dim i As Long - duplicate declaration in the current scope

Comment: @confusedexcel are you using exactly my code or is it a hybrid type deal that you've edited?

Comment: Using it exactly. I copied your codes from above and pasted.

Comment: @confusedexcel dangit, I had moved the `set rangeLabels` so that it was easier to read but broke the function, try it again please

Comment: I still get an error: Runtime error 438 (object doesnt support this property or method)

Comment: @confusedexcel on what line

Comment: 'set the chart source
                .SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(i, "D"), .Cells(i, "O"))   'your sheet confused me on the end column

                'pick the range of labels
                Set rangeLabels = .Range(.Cells(i, "AM"), .Cells(i, "AX"))
            End With

Comment: @confusedexcel fixed that error, let me know how it goes